# Do movies and TV shows use extra-bright flashlights?

Tags: film-techniques, realism, props, lighting

Movie sets are very brightly lit, even for scenes that appear dark onscreen. This is because the more light there is, the better the final picture quality is.

Common flashlights are not particularly bright. It would be hard for them to compete with extra-bright movie lights. However, in movies and TV shows the beam of the flashlight is generally visible, and the beam generally illuminates things clearly.

[image]

In general, are flashlights in movies modified to increase their light output?

Comment: related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/what-kind-of-flashlights-are-used-in-the-x-files-by-the-fbi

Comment: Look at flashlights like Fenix TK-45: plenty powerful. Also keep in mind that digital cameras are much better at picking up such light sources. See also: http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?306513-Flashlights-in-TV-shows-and-movies-(Part-4)

Comment: Plus they'll *enhance* the beams to make them visible.

Answer (score 5):

*Links are mainly to 'educational' refs with background info on each topic, rather than IMDB/wikipedia etc.*

You can see the beam because ["movie smoke"](https://nofilmschool.com/2014/05/fog-smoke-haze-the-swiss-army-knives-of-cinematography-tools) is used in nearly every shot these days. You often can't really 'see' it in the shot, but it makes lights look good.
Earlier this week, they were actually using 'smoke in a can' which I'd never seen before, to supplement the usual smoke machine. [Youtube link to 6 min video on 'smoke in a can'.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqFUucSLKd8&ab_channel=FilmRiot)

Modern cameras can use any old light source, they really don't need anything extra-bright.
Notable recent movies using only natural light include [The Witch](https://variety.com/2016/artisans/in-contention/the-witch-cinematographer-jarin-blaschke-natural-light-1201716424/) & of course [The Revenant](https://variety.com/2015/artisans/production/the-revenant-cinematography-emmanuel-lubezki-1201661435/)

In earlier times it was only possible by using incredibly wide aperture lenses - famously [Kubrick's Barry Lyndon](http://neiloseman.com/barry-lyndon-the-full-story-of-the-famous-f0-7-lenses/) did this.
I have never in my life been anywhere close to a T0.7 lens... they are the stuff of dreams.

Also see Wikipedia - [Theatrical smoke & fog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatrical_smoke_and_fog)